How to unlock Google Family Link, if the time is out of sync?
I use Google FamilyLink to restrict time/access to my kids phone.
Because I do not want fixed time restrictions, I used the following configuration:

The phone is locked from 00:00 to 23:59, i.e., without manual unlock from a parent, the kids do not have access.
Access is granted on request by using the "bonus time" feature.

Unfortunately, a device ran out of battery and lost its time setting.
The situation now is that

The device is offline, i.e., it does not connect to the local WiFi (could not figure out why).
It cannot be unlocked with time-based codes, because the time is wrong on the device.

Is there a way to unlock the device?
ADB is disabled, but recovery mode provides a root shell to the device and TWRP would allow access to the data partition. The device is running LineageOS version 18.1.

What about inserting a SIM card and enabling cellular communication. Or try to enable GPS on lock screen. Cellular and GPS provide time and date, thus can be used as alternative time sources and may allow to sync time and date.

Consider setting up a (short term) unsecured WiFi access point just to get the clock synced.

Thank you @Robert, inserting a SIM card did the trick.

It turned out that inserting a SIM card was the only/easiest way to get the device online and set the correct time and date.
Credits to @Robert for that hint.
